# Buttons and Cartesian Coordinates

Tags: iphone, drag-and-drop, 2d, uibutton

I have this scrollview "eager" to be filled up with buttons (4 per row), and resembling iphone apps icons, I want the user to be able to rearrange them has she/he pleases. If it were one row of buttons only, Apple Autoscroll tutorial app would be an excellent example to follow. Not the case, this is 2D and I cannot figure out how to do it. Couple of ideas tried: An array keeping buttons coordinates as reference; at this moment I'm trying to find out a way to pick up the buttons that have "lower/lesser" coordinates than the one being dragged. I've been searching and researching with no success. Any mathematical algorithm to do this? I suspect there are some other solutions out there seriously tested and robust. Can you pin point some? 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use the `TTLauncherView`?